# Must a Witch leave their Familiar behind when using Dimension Door?

Tags: spells, familiars, pathfinder-2e, teleportation

[Dimension Door](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=69) says:

> Opening a door that bypasses normal space, you instantly transport yourself and any items you're wearing and holding from your current space to a clear space within range you can see. If this would bring **another creature** with you—even if you're carrying it in an extradimensional container—**the spell is lost**.

For balance reasons I can understand not being able to bring your allies with you, but Animal Companions and Familiars (especially for Witches) are an integral part of the character.

I was searching for an exception that says something along the lines "your minion is only a creature when you want it to be", but I could not find any.
Is there any way a Witch can bring their Familiar along?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### I couldn't find an exception

I recently started Night of the Gray Death as a high-level Improved Familiar Attunement Wizard with the Familiar Master archetype, so I was hoping to find some allowance for me to bring my little best friend along when I go wizard sprinting (aka Dimension Door).  I could find no exception, nor even item, that reliably allowed your Familiar to hitch a ride with you.

### Other options

[Dimensional Knot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1004)s, for 60g each, allow you to bring one adjacent creature with you when using Dimension Door at 4th level (giving them Stunned 1).

The [Recall Familiar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=70) Master Ability allows you to spend a full turn, once per day, to bring your Familiar to you after you've teleported.

The [Independent](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=27) Familiar ability allows it to continue traveling toward you to reunite without receiving Commands.

Improved Familiar Attunement Wizards can (probably, ask your GM) use [Call Bonded Item](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1836) to summon their Familiar for one action.